# Can not use a pytorch lightning trainer to train a LLama mode that load in 8 bit

Tags: huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning, llama

i tried to load the model using `model = LlamaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name,load_in_8bit=True,config=model_config))`.The model will be automatically placed on CUDA.Then i trained to construct a lightning model like

```
class MyLLamaModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
```

But when i start training like `trainer = pl.Trainer(devices=4,max_epochs=15,accelerator='gpu',default_root_dir='./checkpoints',limit_train_batches=5,limit_val_batches=1,limit_test_batches=5,strategy='ddp_find_unused_parameters_true')

`,I will meet the bugs that the model does not in same device.
**I could not use 4 device to train a 8 bit model which is from transformers lib.**
I have tried to move the llama model to cpu.But when i use trainer,it still meet the above problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMRjT.png)

Comment: could you share the whole error trace?